# powerball draw question

Tags: probability, statistics, lotteries

This seems intuitive but would like a second opinion.

Powerball with 69 numbers. Need to choose 5 correct (order does not matter).

```
Prediction A: 60, 61, 64, 65, 68
Prediction B: 25, 35, 48, 59, 64
```

When I look at a list of 253 actual powerball drawings, the lowest number (slot 1) is never over 51. I know that 51 or higher for slot 1 is possible but is it correct to say that the likelihood of Prediction A is more of an edge case (due to a high number, 60 in this case, in slot 1)?

Thus, Prediction A is less likely to appear than Prediction B?

Slot 1 does not mean the first ball drawn. Rather, it is the lowest numbered ball after 5 balls are drawn.

Thanks.

Comment: On the flip-side, intuitively, Prediction A likely has a lot of probability of having the highest number in it. Likely enough to negate it's lack of probability of containing the lowest.

Answer (score 8):

It is not correct to say that prediction A is less likely than prediction B.  There are many more possible draws with $25$ as the lowest number than with $60$ as lowest number, but any specific draw is $1$ chance in $69 \choose 5$.  $1,2,3,4,5$ also has the same probability, but I would bet you have never seen it.  The fallacy comes from intuitively lumping the cases into classes.  $25,35,48,59,64$ doesn't have any features that stand out, so you might think of it as a normal draw.  $60,61,64,65,68$ has all the numbers very high, so you think of that group, which is much smaller.  That makes it much less likely to get a draw "like $60,61,64,65,68$" than a draw "like $25,35,48,59,64$"

Comment: Note that "like" is also included in "like $25,35,48,59,64$"

Comment: Thanks Ross M. My confusion comes from looking at empirical data. Using 253 powerball drawings, I aggregated counts for each number into a spreadsheet. Let's say the lowest number from each draw is slot 1, the next number is slot 2, etc. In slot one there are no numbers 51 or higher in this (small) sample of 253 draws. So when looking at the empirical data, seems to imply that 60 as the lowest number (slot 1) is a rare edge case. Given the improbability of 60 in slot 1, as evidenced by the sample, that also makes Prediction A highly unlikely. Can you explain my fallacy?

Comment: On a practical level, is it fair for me to tell someone that they should never use 60 as the lowest number (slot 1) in their numbers? Is that equivalent to saying that they should never use 25 as the lowest number? Another way of asking: although the sample data seems to contradict, it is equally fair to spend $2 on Prediction A numbers as it is on Prediction B numbers?

Comment: Because there are so few cases with $60$ the smallest number, the chance of Prediction A given that $60$ is the smallest number is rather high.  To take an extreme example, count the number of draws that are $1,2,3,4,5$ in one column and everything else in the other.  The first column only occurs once in $69 \choose 5$ times, but if it happens the draw was $1,2,3,4,5$, so we get $1,2,3,4,5$ once in ${69 \choose 5}$ times.  The second happens all the rest, but the draw $2,4,8,9,10$ only happens once in ${69 \choose 5}-1$ times that the second column occurs.

Comment: It is totally unfair to tell somebody they shouldn't use a pick with $60$ the lowest.  **Every specific pick has the same probability**  It is your aggregation that is biased.  If you had to bet on the smallest number, you should bet on $1$.  There are many more choices with $1$ smallest than any other number.